# how can we present the previously entered search criteria in react-awesome-query-builder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react-awesome-query-builder to build query and search. I want to present the previously entered query in the same search when I log in again to the application. I meant some default selected criteria. I googled for a way to implement but unfortunately i would not get any idea.
Below is code

```
class QueryProcessor extends Component{
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state={
  query:null,
}

 this.getChildren=this.getChildren.bind(this);
 let query=null;
 let mainDate=null;

}


getChildren(props) {


 this.query=QbUtils.queryString(props.tree, props.config);
    return (

        <div>
            <div className="query-builder">
                <Builder {...props} />
            </div>


        </div>
    )

}

onChange(tree) {
  //here you can save tree object:
//  var treeJSON = transit.toJSON(tree);
 console.log("tree",tree);

}
 render(){
 let mainData=this.props.rulingList?this.props.rulingList:null;
  console.log("mainData",mainData);



    return(
    <div className="page-content container-fluid header-master">
      <div className="content content-background">
         <div className="col-md-12 custom-back-white header-master">
         <br/>
           <div className="">
           <h1> Query Builder</h1><br/>
           <Query
           {...config}
           //you can pass object here, see treeJSON at onChange
          // value=transit.fromJSON(treeJSON)
           get_children={this.getChildren}
           onChange={this.onChange}

         ></Query><br/>
         <div className="pull-right">
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" onClick={()=>{this.props.ListByQuery(this.query)}}   >Search</button>
         </div>


          <br/>

      </div>

         </div>

    </div>
    </div>

  );
 }
}
```

Can you help me out to implement. Thanks in Advance

Comment: The comments in your code describe what you need to do. Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/transit-immutable-js and on each change save it somewhere and when you start the builder assign to its `value` the json you stored.

Comment: we can save tree structure query after we perform some selection but what i wanted is by default it should render some selection

Comment: Why don't you create the *default* selection once, with the  builder, and extract/save that json to a variable for reuse as the default.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the demo here two ways are presented for serialization and loading tree 
https://github.com/ukrbublik/react-awesome-query-builder/blob/master/examples/demo/demo.js#L18

I've tried the second way using [transit-immutable-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/transit-immutable-js)

```
serializeTree = transit.toJSON;
loadTree = transit.fromJSON;
```

Here's a [Formik](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/field) field component that you can use like this

```
<Field
name="condition"
component={QueryBuilder}
fields={fields}
label="Conditions"
/>
```

The component:

```
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/label-has-for */

import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import get from 'lodash.get';
import { Query, Builder, Utils as QbUtils } from 'react-awesome-query-builder';
import transit from 'transit-immutable-js';
import 'react-awesome-query-builder/css/styles.scss';
import 'react-awesome-query-builder/css/compact_styles.scss';
import { Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import config from './config';

const QueryBuilder = ({
  field,
  form: { touched, errors, setFieldValue },
  type,
  id,
  label,
  className,
  fields,
  ...props
}) => {
  const getChildren = queryProps => {
    return (
      <div className="query-builder">
        <Builder {...queryProps} />
      </div>
    );
  };
  return (
    <Form.Group className={className} controlId={field.name}>
      {label && <Form.Label>{label}</Form.Label>}
      <Form.Control
        as={Query}
        get_children={getChildren}
        isInvalid={get(touched, field.name) && get(errors, field.name)}
        onChange={tree => {
          setFieldValue(field.name, {
            tree: transit.toJSON(tree),
            mongo: JSON.stringify(
              QbUtils.mongodbFormat(tree, { ...config, fields })
            )
          });
        }}
        fields={fields}
        {...config}
        {...props}
        value={field.value ? transit.fromJSON(field.value.tree) : null}
      />
      <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
        {get(errors, field.name)}
      </Form.Control.Feedback>
    </Form.Group>
  );
};

QueryBuilder.propTypes = {
  field: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  form: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  fields: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  type: PropTypes.string,
  className: PropTypes.string,
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  error: PropTypes.string,
  label: PropTypes.string,
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number])
};

QueryBuilder.defaultProps = {
  type: 'input',
  className: '',
  value: null,
  label: null,
  error: null
};

export default QueryBuilder;
```

Example config file : https://github.com/ukrbublik/react-awesome-query-builder#config-format

Answer (score 1):

I don't recomment using transit anymore.
In latest versions I've added utils to save tree to json and load from json:

- [loadTree](https://github.com/ukrbublik/react-awesome-query-builder#loadtree-jsvalue-config---immutable)
- [getTree](https://github.com/ukrbublik/react-awesome-query-builder#gettree-immutablevalue-light--true---object)

See new examples

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30196293)